# How to submit value from DIV element into a PHP-based form

Tags: php, jquery, html

I have a DIV element that works like a checkbox. I want to submit its 'value' attribute into a PHP-based form, but it won't pass the DIV response to the PHP file.

HTML:

```
 <form action="test.php" method="post">
    <div id="test1" value="testvalue" name="test" checked="checked"></div>
    <input type="submit" />
 </form>
```

PHP:

```
<?php
$test = $_POST['test'];
echo $test;
?>
```

Comment: its a custom checkbox i created with jquery.

Comment: `div` element is _custom checkbox_?

Comment: yes it has a background that changes on click.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

Only form elements are posted back to the server.  You need to create an input element if you want the value sent.  You could consider making an `<input type="hidden" name="test" value="testvalue"`.

In response to your custom checkbox made with jQuery comment, you could use jQuery to set the value of the hidden input element.  This will let you continue to use the div but have a value that gets sent back to the server.

Comment: you forgot to add a 'name' attribute to your input: `<input type="hidden" name="test" value="testvalue">`

Comment: I edited it to include name, good call!

Answer (score 3):

What @andrew-jackman says is correct, but i still did a fiddle with jQuery for the kicks.

I included a hidden field to manage the data and make used jQuery's toggle to replicate the checkbox functionality

```
<form action="test.php" method="post">
  <div id="test1" value="testvalue"  checked="checked">
    <input type="hidden" name="test" id="hiddenfield" />
  </div>
<input type="submit" />
```

javascript

```
$('div#test1').toggle(function(){
  $('input#hiddenfield').val('checked');
  alert($('input#hiddenfield').val());
},function(){
  $('input#hiddenfield').val('');
  alert($('input#hiddenfield').val())
})
```

http://jsfiddle.net/kumiau/nPEYw/1/