# How To Pass A Div Value As Input In A Form?

Tags: jquery, html, ajax

I am trying to pass a HTML Div Value(The Whole HTML Code Inside The Div) As An Input Value In A Form Via Ajax. 
Here Is My Form Code:
The Div "Fetch_Applicant" fetches a table dynamically which i want to pass via ajax. I Have Updated The DIV With The Table.

```
     //Form Starts
    <form name="mail_applicant" novalidate id="mail_applicant" action="" method="post" >
        <div id="fetch_applicant">
<table style="width:100%">
  <tr>
    <td>Jill</td>
    <td>Smith</td> 
    <td>50</td>
  </tr>
  <tr>
    <td>Eve</td>
    <td>Jackson</td> 
    <td>94</td>
  </tr>
</table>
</div>  
        <input name="mail_id" id="mail_id" value="" type="email" required />    
        <button type="submit" id="mail_applicant" name="mail_applicant" >Send Mail</button>                       
        </form>     //Form Ends

        <div id="fetch_applicant_mail"></div> //This Is Where I Am Printing The Status Of The Post.
```

Here Is My AJAX Code:

```
<script type="text/javascript">
$(document).ready(function (e) {

    $("#mail_applicant").on('submit',(function(e) { /*On Submit Of Form Named Mail Applicant */

        e.preventDefault();
        $.ajax({
            url: "send_mail_applicant.php", /*Posting The Data*/
            type: "POST",
            data:  new FormData(this),
            contentType: false,
            cache: false,
            processData:false,
            success: function(data)
            {

            $("#fetch_applicant_mail").html(data); /*Fetching POST Status*/


            },
            error: function() 
            {
            }           
       });
    }));
});
</script> /*Script Ends*/
```

Here Is My PHP Code:

```
<?php


echo "Content".$_POST['fetch_applicant'];
echo "Mail-id:".$_POST['mail_id'];
  $to = $_POST['mail_id'];
  $subject = "Mail Data";
  $message = $_POST['fetch_applicant'];
  $headers = "From: The Server <bot@abcd.com>" . "\r\n" .
             "Content-type: text/html" . "\r\n";

  mail($to, $subject, $message, $headers);



?>
```

When i am submitting the form, the mail id is getting posted but the div content is not getting posted. It remains null. The value for `$_POST['fetch_applicant']` is always getting NULL.

NOTE That This Link: [how to submit a div value in a form](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14666484/how-to-submit-a-div-value-in-a-form) havent helped.

Comment: You cannot send div values as they are part of Form. Either you clone this div value to some hidden field before form is submitted, or, you should select each form element and post those values.

Comment: @Arijit, What should be the value of `$_POST['fetch_applicant']`? What you want to pass as it's value?

Comment: Would be great if you can help me out with the code.

Comment: keep your value in input box using hidden textbox. surly it will help you

Comment: A table which is fetched dynamically into the div. That is working perfectly fine. But when i am trying to mail the div content(i.e the table) it isnt passing the values.

Comment: @ArijitAich 1. in suceess(data) if data is object then .html will not show your  result  2. are you returning null from serer side. if not then it should be text then .html will help you 3. if this both method not working then console.log (data ) in success and reply me hear will help you accordingly

Comment: @ArijitAich, So, do you want to pass the whole elements inside your `div` as a string?

Comment: I want to pass the whole html code. Since the table will be sent as mail body.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Solution: Fetch The Same Table Value In A Hidden Textarea. Then Send The Value Of The Text Area As Input.

AJAX Code:

```
<script type="text/javascript">
$(document).ready(function (e) {

    $("#mail_applicant").on('submit',(function(e) { /*On Submit Of Form Named Mail Applicant */

        e.preventDefault();
        $.ajax({
            url: "send_mail_applicant.php", /*Posting The Data*/
            type: "POST",
            data:  new FormData(this),
            contentType: false,
            cache: false,
            processData:false,
            success: function(data)
            {

            $("#fetch_applicant_mail").html(data); /*Fetching POST Status*/


            },
            error: function() 
            {
            }           
       });
    }));
});



  function SetData()
     {
  $("#hddenID").val($("#fetch_applicant_mail").html()); //here we have store value into hidden field
      }
    </script>
```

HTML Code:

```
<div id="fetch_applicant"></div> //Fetches The Table Here
                                    <form name="mail_applicant" novalidate id="mail_applicant" action="" method="post" onclick="SetData()" >
    <textarea hidden id="fetch_applicant_m" name="fetch_applicant_m" value="" type="text" required ></textarea> //Fetches The Same Table Here AS Well    
    <input name="mail_id" id="mail_id" value="" type="email" required />    
    <button type="submit" id="mail_applicant" name="mail_applicant" >Send Mail</button>   
     <input name="fetch_applicant_mail" id="hddenID" value="" type="hidden" />                   
    </form>     

  <div id="fetch_applicant_mail"></div> //Fetches The Value Passed Through Ajax After POST.
```

PHP Code:

```
<?php


echo "Content".$_POST['fetch_applicant_m'];
echo "Mail-id:".$_POST['mail_id'];
  $to = $_POST['mail_id'];
  $subject = "Mail Data";
  $message = "'".$_POST['fetch_applicant_m']."'";
  $headers = "From: The Server <bot@abcd.com>" . "\r\n" .
             "Content-type: text/html" . "\r\n";

  mail($to, $subject, $message, $headers);



?>
```

Answer (score 1):

As you are preventing the submit and using AJAX to send the data instead of submitting it, you just have to pass the value of the div:

**Update:** This code that I post should work as expected. I suggest you hold your console open when you send the data to avoid JS errors.

```
<script type="text/javascript">
    $(document).ready(function() {
        $("#mail_applicant").on('submit', (function(e) {
            e.preventDefault();
            $.ajax({
                url: "send_mail_applicant.php",
                type: "post",
                data: {
                    fetch_applicant: $('#fetch_applicant').html(),
                    mail_id: $('#mail_id').val()
                },
                success: function(data) {
                    $("#fetch_applicant_mail").html(data);
                }
            });
            return false;
        }));
    });
</script>
```

PHP Code:

```
<?php
    $to = $_POST['mail_id'];
    $subject = "Mail Data";
    $message = $_POST['fetch_applicant'];
    $headers = "From: The Server <bot@abcd.com>" . "\r\n" .
             "Content-type: text/html" . "\r\n";

    mail($to, $subject, $message, $headers);
?>
```

Comment: Will it be helpful, since i want to pass the whole html code of the div contents. It will be used as mail body.

Comment: If you want to pass the whole code of `#fetch_applicant`, use `.html()`. I updated the answer.

Comment: None of the values got passed with this code. Even the mail id did'nt which  was previously passing.

Comment: Sorry, is obvious that you have to pass the rest of the data as parameters! I'll update the answer to show you what I mean

Comment: It didn't work. This time also both the data's didnt work.

Comment: I am not sure what are you doing exactly. Can you update the question with your current code? If you can include your PHP code where you have your `$_POST` variables would be nice too.

Comment: Ok. Please do it, I will be waiting.

Answer (score 0):

Can you try like this:-

```
 //Form Starts
<form name="mail_applicant" novalidate id="mail_applicant" action="" method="post" onclick="SetData()" >
    <div id="fetch_applicant"></div>    
    <input name="mail_id" id="mail_id" value="" type="email" required />    
    <button type="submit" id="mail_applicant" name="mail_applicant" >Send Mail</button>   
     <input name="fetch_applicant_mail" id="hddenID" value="" type="hidden" />  //Added hidden field                   
    </form>     //Form Ends

  <div id="fetch_applicant_mail"></div>
```

On Submit

```
<script type="text/javascript">
$(document).ready(function (e) {

    $("#mail_applicant").on('submit',(function(e) { /*On Submit Of Form Named Mail Applicant */

        e.preventDefault();
        $.ajax({
            url: "send_mail_applicant.php", /*Posting The Data*/
            type: "POST",
            data:  new FormData(this),
            contentType: false,
            cache: false,
            processData:false,
            success: function(data)
            {

            $("#fetch_applicant_mail").html(data); /*Fetching POST Status*/


            },
            error: function() 
            {
            }           
       });
    }));
});



  function SetData()
     {
  $("#hddenID").val($("#fetch_applicant_mail").html()); //here we have store value into hidden field
      }
    </script> /*Script Ends*/
```

Comment: what is difference between your answer and op quetion

Comment: please check comment i have added. Added hidden field and stored value

Comment: Nope. Its Not Working. Its only passing the email.

Comment: Didnt Work. It The Same. Only Passing The Email.

Comment: can you convert button to input type="button"

Answer (score 0):

`new FormData(this)` will not generate a property for `fetch_applicant`, because `FormData()` will be looking only on `input` elements inside your form.

So, you need to add the property `fetch_applicant` and assign it the value manually.

**How**

You can use a variable to hold your all data which are generated by `new FormData(this)` and add a property to it and assign it's value.

```
var myData = new FormData(this);
myData.fetch_applicant = $('#fetch_applicant').html();// It will create a new property and assign it with the html content inside your dive
```

So, now you can pass this variable `myData` as parameter to your ajax call.

So your final code will be,

$(document).ready(function (e) {

```
$("#mail_applicant").on('submit',(function(e) { /*On Submit Of Form Named Mail Applicant */

    e.preventDefault();
    var myData = new FormData(this);
    myData.fetch_applicant = $('#fetch_applicant').html();// It will create a new property and assign it with the html content inside your dive

    $.ajax({
        url: "send_mail_applicant.php", /*Posting The Data*/
        type: "POST",
        data:  myData, // Pass your myData here.
        contentType: false,
        cache: false,
        processData:false,
        success: function(data)
        {

        $("#fetch_applicant_mail").html(data); /*Fetching POST Status*/


        },
        error: function() 
        {
        }           
     });
  }));
});

</script> /*Script Ends*/
```

Comment: This code is not calling the ajax function. The page is simply getting refreshed.

Comment: @ArijitAich, ok. So, don't submit your form from a submit button. Could you please handle the button click and on that do this method to submit your form with custom data.