# Using DIV like dependent dropdown lists [PHP + JS]

Tags: javascript, php

I have a DIV element as drop-down in PHP as below:

```
<div id="files" value="fileselect" selected="selected">Choose Folder1
<input type="hidden" name="test" id="hiddenfield" />
</div>
<div id="files2" value="fileselect2"  selected="selected">Choose Folder2
<input type="hidden" name="test2" id="hiddenfield2" />
</div>
```

Now I try to get the value of selected option as follows:

```
<?php $content = ?>
  <script type = text/javscript>
  document.getElementById("files").value;
  </script>
  <?php echo $content; ?>
```

but I get unknown variable $content error.

And, I tried to create 'change' event handling in DIV element as follows:

```
$(document).ready(function()
  {
   //Bind a change event to the folder selector
    $("#files").change(function()
    {
      var dir = $(this).val();
                
      // Get file names in directory dir and pass it to the next drop-down DIV
      $.get("listfiles.php", {"dir":dir}, function(response){
        //Show the files
        $("#files2").html(response);
        //alert($('#files2 option:selected').val());
        alert(response);
        $(response).appendTo('#hiddenfield2');
      });
    });
  });
```

But this doesn't help passing the 'response' to the second DIV "files2".

I need to use the two DIVs like dependent drop-down lists. I make the dropdown-list "selection1" interact with DIV "selection2" like dependent dropdowns as follows:

```
    <select name="field1" id="selection1">

    <option selected="selected" name ="selection1">Folder 1</option>

    <?php

    $selections = array('Folder A', 'Folder B', 'Folder C');

    foreach($selection as $selections){

    ?>

    <option value="<?php echo strtolower($selection); ?>"><?php echo 
         $selection; ?></option>

    <?php

    }

    ?>


</select>

$("#selection1").change(function()
        {
                var dir = $(this).val();

                $.get("listdirs1.php", {"dir":dir}, function(response){
                        //Show the files
                        $("#files").html(response);
                    //  alert($('#selection2 option:selected').val());
                        //alert(response);
                        $(response).appendTo('#selection2');
                });
        });
```

But this doesn't work in case both "selection1" and "selection2" are DIVs.

I already referred to [how to submit a div value in a form stackoverflow answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14666484/how-to-submit-a-div-value-in-a-form)

I am all new to PHP and JavaScript. Please help. Thanks in advance.

Comment: JavaScript and PHP code cannot interact directly like that; PHP runs on the server; the result is sent to the browser, and that's when JS starts. Also note that <div>s don't have an onchange event; only <input>s and the like do. The jquery snippet looks more or less ok, but how exactly are you turning divs into dropdowns? Are you using a plugin/library for that?

Comment: Don't post code as comment; edit your question instead

Comment: Please check. I have edited the code now.

Comment: A div is just a container. It doesn't have a `change` event. Again, how does a div become a dropdown? Do you mean to use `<select>` and `<option>` instead? Or are you using a library that turns div into a custom dropdown?

Comment: I just use $.get() to generate values  as 'response' using dropdown-list values. Then I pass this 'response'  to DIV using ' $("#files").html(response); '

Comment: ...but you're doing this *inside* `$("#selection1").change(...)` which means it'll NEVER HAPPEN... unless you have, say, a `<select id="selection1">` with a bunch of options, but if so, put the relevant HTML in the question

Comment: I want to have dependent drop-down lists without using mysql database.

Comment: "selection1" is drop-down list's ID, and "selection2" is DIV element's ID. The code works in this case, but not when both are DIV elements.

Comment: There is no dropdown anywhere in your question's code. Put the dropdown HTML in the question. Why is that so hard? If you don't cooperate, you're on your own

Comment: Sorry, I forgot. Thought I had it already. Now edited. Please check.

Comment: Here's a minimal example: https://jsfiddle.net/khrismuc/x6yodm2p/ Good luck!

Comment: Great! Thank you very much. I will incorporate it my code and will get back asap.

Comment: It works great with two dropdown-down lists, but doesn't work if I have a third drop-down list dependent on the second drop-down list. I updated all relevant variables and element tags. Please help.

Comment: I was able to tweak it. Thank you again for directing.